# PHP - array_push converting JSON array to object

Tags: php

I am trying to add an object ("new_item") to an array if objects in a master JSON object ("master"). If the new object ID already exists in the array I first remove that object from the array before then adding it again afterwards (so there is only one entry per ID).

For some reason when I do this the Array of objects gets converted to a list of objects which I don't want.

This doesn't happen if I only remove the duplicate or allow duplicates, it only seems to happen when I remove one element and then add another.

```
$object = '{"master":[{"id":"1","author":"A"},{"id":"2","author":"B"}]}';
$object = json_decode($object);

$new_item = '{"id":"2","author":"B"}';
$new_item = json_decode($new_item);

foreach ( $object->master as $key => $item ) {
    if ( $item->id == $new_item->id ) {
        unset($object->master[$key]);
    }
}   

if ( count($object->master) == 0  ) {
    $object->master = Array($new_item);
} else {
    array_push($object->master, $new_item); 
}

echo json_encode($object);
```

Outputs

```
{"master":{"0":{"id":"1","author":"A"},"2":{"id":"2","author":"B"}}}
```

As oppose to

```
{"master":[{"id":"1","author":"A"},{"id":"2","author":"B"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode()` only encodes an array as a JSON array if the indexes are sequential starting from `0`. Otherwise, it's encoded as an object. Since you do `unset($object->master[$key])`, you create a gap in the indexes, so you get an object, as there's no other way to indicate that the array doesn't have anything at index 1.

You can use `array_values()` to renumber the indexes, to get rid of the gap.

There's no need to check if the count is 0 before pushing the new item, since you can push onto an empty array.

```
array_push($object->master, $new_item); 
$object->master = array_values($object->master);
```

You say that the problem doesn't happen if you only remove the duplicate without adding another. It should still happen, unless the duplicate happens to be the last element. Then there's no gap in the index sequence, so it meets the criteria to be encoded as an array.

If IDs are unique, another solution would be to simply replace the duplicate with the new item, instead of unsetting it and later pushing the new item.

```
$found = false;
foreach ( $object->master as $key => $item ) {
    if ( $item->id == $new_item->id ) {
        $object->master[$key] == $new_item;
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}   

if (!$found) {
    $object->master[] = $new_item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use this:

```
$object = array_values($object);
```